# Approximating $\ln(1+2x) = 2x$ using linear approximation

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

The question is as follows:

> Use the linear approximation formula
> $$\boxed{f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) +f'(x)\Delta x}$$
> to show that $\ln(2x+1) \approx 2x$ for small values of $x$.

I am having trouble understanding what $\Delta x$ is supposed to be in the formula given.

Also should $f(x)  = \ln(1+2x)$ or  $f(x) = \ln(1+x)$. Will that make any difference?

Comment: $\Delta x$ is a small change in x; eg: $f(1 + 10^{-5}) \approx f(1) + f'(1)\times 10^{-5}$

Comment: Hint:  plug in f(x)= ln(x),  x=1 into the formula.

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite the boxed identity using a different variable:

$$\boxed{f(z + \Delta z) \approx f(z) + f'(z) \Delta z}.$$

Now choose $$f(x) = \log x = \ln x, \\ z = 1, \\ \Delta z = 2x.$$

Comment: Does the approximation hold true for all values of x then? Or just small values?

Comment: @Justuraveragemathsstudent The boxed equation uses an approximate equality symbol, $\approx$.  Then it uses $\Delta z$ to indicate a "small" increment, so if $2x$ is too large, then the approximation becomes poor.  Finally, you can just try some values, such as $x = 0.001$, to get $\ln (1.002) = 0.001998\ldots \approx 0.002$, but if $x = 10$, then obviously $\ln(21) = 3.044522 \ldots \not\approx 20$.